# Setup apache2 to forward to Glassfish 4

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, glassfish-4

I have a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 server and a simple html website running with apache 2.
An SSL certificate is also installed. Apache2 is already configured to forward automatically to https.
Furthermore I have a java application running on Glassfish 4 under contextroot `myApp`. I can access it under `http://mydomain.io:8080/myApp`
How can I configure apache to forward all requests `https://mydomain.io/myApp/` to Glassfish. I don't want to use `mod_jk`, just apache.
Thanks

UPDATE
In the mean time I tried with mod_rewrite this:

```
ProxyPass /myApp/ http://localhost:8080/myApp/
ProxyPassReverse /myApp/ http://localhost:8080/myApp/
```

in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`
but it's not working!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem by inserting following lines

`ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/` 
in the VirtualHost configuration file located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. 
 Like suggested in this [website](https://serverfault.com/questions/505316/ssl-setup-with-apache-in-front-of-tomcat).